# ActionScript 3 - Resize a MovieClip dynamically by browser BUT keep PROPORTIONS

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, resize, movieclip

I have a Movie Clip with dimensions: 500x400. Instance name is: "main". I have the following code:

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.events.Event;

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.addEventListener (Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);

// initialize sizing
resizeHandler (null);

function resizeHandler (event:Event):void {
var sw:Number = stage.stageWidth;
var sh:Number = stage.stageHeight;

  main.height = sh;
  main.width = sw;

}
```

How can I keep proportions on resizing and maximum size for MovieClip to be 500x400?

Comment: when the stage becomes available, you should store the stageWidth/stageHeight ratio in a variable, then reuse that in the resizeHandler to the new dimensions proportional. For a simple simple, other scale modes might be handy

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don't know is ActionScript3 to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code should do the job:

```
if (stage.stageWidth/500 < stage.stageHeight/400)
{
    main.scaleX = stage.stageWidth/500;
    main.scaleY = main.scaleX;
}else{
    main.scaleX = stage.stageHeight/400;
    main.scaleY = main.scaleX;
}
```

Comment: Your code does the same thing, like my code. The proportions aren't held. Maximum size for MovieClip doesn't work. Flash document size is: 500x400, and publish settings are: HTML - Default scale (show all) and 100x100 percent for dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head, so not 100% it's the correct syntax, but you should get the idea:

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.events.Event;

var ratio:Number = Number(stage.stageWidth)/stage.stageWidth;//you need to check if stage isn't null and this ratio is valid

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.addEventListener (Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);


// initialize sizing
resizeHandler (null);

function resizeHandler (event:Event):void {
var sw:Number = stage.stageWidth;
var sh:Number = stage.stageHeight;
  //make with width same as stage
  main.width = sw;
  main.height = sh/ratio;//keep height proprtional
  //or you can try the other way around if you want - make main.height = sh and main.width =  sh * ratio;

}
```

Comment: Proportion works! But how can I set size restriction (500x400) for MovieClip?

Comment: If you're movieclip's dimensions are 500x400 by default(with no scaling) and you want to keep it as the same size, why do you then change the width and height in the resize handler ? Do you get the desired behaviour by commenting out those two lines in the resize handler ?

Comment: I want a restriction for MAXIMUM size 500x400. If I have for example 1920x1200 resolution, my MovieClip will have 1300x1000 (aproximative size). I want to resize MovieClip and constain proportions when the size of browser widow is lower than resolution, and set a maximum size of 500x400. I hope you understand what I wanted to say.

Comment: I wish this was made clear from the start. Try @Tianzhen Lin's answer, it looks accurate. Also, if file size isn't a problem and you're using the Flash IDE, you could use the UILoader component and pass the MovieClip's Liinkage id

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick regardless movie clip's proportion.  If you wish to enforce 500 by 400 proportion, you may assign movieClipRatio as 500 / 400.

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.events.Event;

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.addEventListener (Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
var movieClipRatio:Number = main.width / main.height;

// initialize sizing
resizeHandler (null);

function resizeHandler (event:Event):void {
    var sw:Number = stage.stageWidth;
    var sh:Number = stage.stageHeight;

    if ( sw == 0 || sh == 0 ) {
        return; // special case to avoid
    }

    var stageRatio:Number = sw / sh;

    if ( stageRatio > movieClipRatio )  {
        // stage is proportionally wider than movieClip
        // resize by height
        main.width *= sh / main.height;
        main.height = sh;
    } else {
        // stage is proportionally taller than movieClip
        // resize by width
        main.height *= sw / main.width;
        main.width = sw;
    }

}
```